# Python with Selenium "try" and "except" not working correctly

Tags: python, selenium

I have a Python code with Selenium where I look up songs and download them from a website. The program searches and if it finds the song it clicks the download button. My problem is that if it doesn't find the song for some reason, it just stops and doesn't continue with the remaining songs. I tried using "try "and except" like this:

```
try:
    dlbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mcont"]/div[6]/div/a/span[1]')
    dlbutton.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

My only problem is if this code is running my program will get to the download page but not actually press the button (which dlbutton.click()) should do.

I don't want to use try and except if it's not necessary. I just want my program to skip the entry if it cannot find the download button.

Comment: Which webpage are you scrapping?

Comment: Are you sure the xpath is working? Its possible the code is doing exactly what you want but the find_element_by_xpath portion doesn't match the actual webpage, or there's another popup after the button is clicked that isn't being clicked.

Comment: The xpath is working fine. If I run the command without the try and except commands the program runs fine but when it gets to a song it doesn't find it can't continue

Comment: I'm scrapping https://en.muzmo.org/. For educational purposes only of course.